# Managed Package VF Page Showing "Site Temporarily Unavailable" on Community Site

Tags: lightning-community, digital-experience, community-cloud

I have a managed package VF (Visualforce) page that I'm trying to access on my community site. However, when I navigate to the URL by appending "/apex/namespace__vfpage" to the community site URL, I encounter the error message "Site Temporarily Unavailable."

Here are the steps I have already taken to troubleshoot the issue:

Checked VF page permission: I have confirmed that the profile assigned to the community users has the necessary permissions to access the VF page.

Enabled the "Enable Experience" checkbox: I have made sure that the "Enable Experience" checkbox is enabled for the VF page, allowing it to be accessed within the community context.

Despite these steps, I'm still unable to access the VF page and encountering the "Site Temporarily Unavailable" error.

Could anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and make the managed package VF page accessible within the community site? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check permissions for accessing the VF page's apex controller(s)/controller extension(s)?